# PHP websocket script running as daemon stops working after a while

Tags: php, daemon, websocket

I start my websocket script like so:

```
nohup php server.php &
```

and I close the ssh client and it seems to be working fine for a while, but after say half an hour or so it stops working, any idea why and how to make it permanent?

Comment: Read up on the init system for your OS/Distro and make a proper service out of it.

Comment: Debug your script by making proper logging into it, and research your logs why this happens.

Answer (score -3):

Try to use Tmux (or screen):

```
apt-get install tmux
```

after:

```
 tmux attach; tmux new
```

and finally:

```
php server.php
```

Docs https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux

Comment: Sorry but I am not very knowledgeable about server administration, am I supposed to have the `apt-get` command as is in my ssh, because I don't?

Comment: @user6562256 `apt-get` is used on Debian and derivatives. Which OS are you running? Additionally, it requires privileges, so become `root` or use `sudo`.

Comment: `tmux` / `screen` are **not** a replacement for proper integration into an init system.